# ANTLR nested semantic predicates with wildcard operator

Tags: antlr, antlr3, abstract-syntax-tree, antlrworks

I created a grammar for a Scheme-like language interpreter. Initially, I had one semantic predicate for the if-then-else statement to control evaluation i.e. when the conditional is true only the 'then' is evaluated; when it's false, only the 'else' is evaluated. To add type-checking functionality, I added a second semantic predicate enclosing the first one. It's a hack, though, because to type-check or evaluate I have to manually change the global boolean `typeCheck` to either true or false.

The AST for the IF statement now has two branches. The first (IFT) is for type-checking the IF statement's arguments. [this is why of two predicates; to type-check, all arguments must be evaluated] The second branch (IFE) is for evaluating the short-circuiting if-then-else. The problem started when I added a second semantic predicate that enclosed the first, getting the infamous "no viable alternative at input" error. After getting nowhere slowly, I created new grammars with just the essentials. Same issue. Here is the stripped down AST:

[image: IF AST]

Though I have never experienced one, I've seen issues reported on SO with the ANTLR IDE in Eclipse. So I fired up ANTLRWorks, debugged the parser grammar, then tried to debug the tree grammar. Versions 1.4.3 and 1.4.2 both popup this box, "*warning: the grammar used by the remote parser is not the same*". I click OK then in the debugger click Step Forward just once and the java.exe*32 process dies. As a final test, I manually compiled from the command line with antlr-3.3 and antlr-3.4 complete jars, no change.

The parser:

```
grammar NestedSemPreds;

options {
    output = AST;
    ASTLabelType = CommonTree;
}

tokens {
    IF;
    IFT;
    IFE;
}   

/** parser rules **/
ifstmt  : '(' 'if' COND THEN ELSE ')' NEWLN
            -> ^(IF ^(IFT COND THEN ELSE)
                    ^(IFE COND THEN ELSE)
                )
        ;

/** lexer rules **/
COND    : 'true' ; 
THEN    : 'then' ;
ELSE    : 'else' ;
COMMENT :   ('//' .* NEWLN) { skip(); } ; //for lines in datafile I don't want processed
NEWLN   :   '\r'? '\n' ;
WS      :   (' '|'\t')+ { skip(); } ;
```

The tree grammar:

```
tree grammar treeEval;

options {
    tokenVocab = NestedSemPreds;
    ASTLabelType = CommonTree;
}

@members {
    boolean typeCheck = false;
}

ifstmt 
@init {
    boolean condition = true;
}
 : ^(IF (  
           {typeCheck}? => //{System.out.println("typeCheck is true");}
                            ^(IFT COND THEN ELSE) {System.out.println("IFT COND THEN ELSE");}
                            ^(IFE . . .) {System.out.println("    SKIP IFE WITH . WILDCARD");}
        | {!typeCheck}? => //{System.out.println("typeCheck is false");} 
                            ^(IFT . . .) {System.out.println("skip ift with . wildcard");}
                            ^(IFE COND
                                    (  {condition}? => ({System.out.println("    condition is true");}
                                                       THEN . {System.out.println("        evaluate THEN");})
                                    | {!condition}? => ({System.out.println("    condition is false");}
                                                      . ELSE {System.out.println("        evaluate else");})
                                    )//close inner predicate
                             )//close ^IFE
        )//close outer predicate
    )//close ^IF
 ;
```

I couldn't find any particular issues on nested semantic predicates, but I didn't find any examples either. Why is this code failing? Any ideas on the issue with ANTLRWorks debugger?

Comment: @BartKiers: got an error editing my comment to you. Thx for your answer! I now know that a predicate for the 2nd option isn't always needed. I simply mimicked the example in _The Definitive ANTLR Reference_, p146. Yes, using actual tokens works but it breaks short-circuiting in the ifstmt (reqd for recursive function call support). My interpreter is more complex (eg. THEN & ELSE can be nested function calls or expr's) than this stripped-down test case created just to isolate the problem.

Comment: yeah, I removed my answer. I might have misunderstood what you were trying to do, and/or your stripped down grammar wasn't a good representation of your entire grammar, so parts of my answer didn't make sense. And since you posted an answer yourself already, I removed mine instead of editing the confusing parts out. Good to hear you resolved the issue, of course!

Comment: I probably could have worded it better. Anyway, all's well that ends well and thanks again for the hint that led to the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Bart's comment about not needing to "add a predicate before the second alternative", I did some additional testing. All tested options were valid syntax so I think this is an ANTLR bug. To cut to the chase, here is what works:

```
ifstmt 
@init {
    boolean condition = true;
}
 : ^(IF (  
           {typeCheck}? => ^(IFT COND THEN ELSE) {System.out.println("IFT COND THEN ELSE");}
                           . //MUST use only one dot
        | {!typeCheck}? => . //also works with ^(IFT . . .) here
                            ^(IFE COND
                                    (  {condition}? => ({System.out.println("    condition is true");}
                                                       THEN . {System.out.println("        evaluate THEN");})
                                    | {!condition}? => //this inner 2nd predicate not required
                                                      . ELSE {System.out.println("        evaluate else");})
                                    )//close inner predicates
                             )//close ^IFE
        )//close outer predicates
    )//close ^IF
 ;
```

These two steps are **required**:

1. Both outer predicates, `{typeCheck}?` and `{!typeCheck}?`, are necessary.
2. The first outer predicate, a single `.` operator to skip the whole subtree

As noted in the code sample, it still works with either of these two syntax changes:

1. The second *outer* predicate, `{!typeCheck}?`, can use a single `.` or the original `^(IFT . . .)` syntax.
2. The second *inner* predicate *is* optional, as Bart mentioned.

Another solution that worked was to manually process the node stream and add appropriate code, but that's not as clean as letting ANTLR do its thing.